# Problema con array en Python

Tags: python, array

Estoy empezando con `Python` y tengo un problema con el código que estoy haciendo...

```
from numpy import *
import random

def busquedaLineal(buscado, arreglo):
    encontrado = 0
for i in range(len(arreglo)):
    if arreglo[i] == buscado:
        encontrado = 1
return encontrado

arreglo = random.sample(range(25), 10)
buscado = random.sample(range(25), 1)

print arreglo
print buscado

buscarElemento = busquedaLineal(buscado, arreglo)

print buscarElemento

if buscarElemento == 1:
   print 'Si se encontro en el arreglo'
 else:
    print 'No se encontro en el arreglo'
```

el ciclo `for` lo he cambiado por usar solamente arreglo o len(arreglo) pero no me funciona, para el dato de retorno (encontrado) siempre sale 0 (no encontrado) aunque el número aleatorio sí se encuentre en el arreglo. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primera línea en la terminal: arreglo (random)

Segunda línea en la terminal: número que buscaremos en el arreglo (random)

Tercera línea en la terminal: 0 que regresa de la función de `búsquedaLineal` (no se encontró)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón es muy simple, `random.sample()` retorna una lista. Cuando haces `buscado = random.sample(range(25), 1)` obtienes una lista de un elemento, por ejemplo:

> [2]

Lo que estás haciendo es **comparar** cada elemento de tu lista `arreglo` (que son **enteros**) y ver si es igual a **una lista**. Esto nunca va a dar `True`, porque estas comparando un lista con un int, cuando llega al 17 en tu lista  `arreglo` la comparación es:

```
if 17 == [17]:
```

esto siempre es `False`, debería ser:

```
if 17 == 17:
```

Simplemente desempaqueta el elemento de la lista `buscando`:

```
import random

def busquedaLineal(buscado, arreglo):
    encontrado = 0
    for i in range(len(arreglo)):
        if arreglo[i] == buscado:
            encontrado = 1
    return encontrado

arreglo = random.sample(range(25), 10)
buscado = random.sample(range(25), 1)[0] #<<<<<Usamos el indice para obtener el entero

print arreglo
print buscado
buscarElemento = busquedaLineal(buscado, arreglo)

print buscarElemento

if buscarElemento:
    print 'Si se encontro en el arreglo'
else:
    print 'No se encontro en el arreglo'
```

No obstante, dos observaciones:

- En Python no recorras una lista u otro iterable usando índices, usa `for-in`, es mucho más 'pythónico' y más eficiente:

  ```
  def busquedaLineal(buscado, arreglo):
      for i in arreglo:
          if i == buscado:
              return 1
      return 0
  ```

  Observa que he cambiado la forma de retornar. Lo que quieres saber es si el número está en el arreglo, es más eficiente retornar 1 en cuanto lo encuentras y no recorrer siempre el array al completo. Esto evita además el uso de una variable intermedia (`encontrado`) que es innecesaria, a no ser que pretendas contar las veces que aparece.
- Por otro lado, esto ya existe en Python implementado de forma eficiente e intuitiva: `if buscado in arreglo`:

  ```
  import random

  arreglo = random.sample(range(25), 10)
  buscado = random.sample(range(25), 1)[0]

  print arreglo
  print buscado

  if buscado in arreglo:
      print 'Si se encontro en el arreglo'
  else:
      print 'No se encontro en el arreglo'
  ```

Comment: ¡Hola, FJSevilla! Muchas gracias por la ayuda, literalmente comencé a estudiar python el día de hoy (ya lo notaste jeje) y estaba atorado, tu solución resolvió el problema y me quedo con tus observaciones para mejorar la calidad del código, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Como consejo, si inicias en Python, cuida siempre la tabulación de tus programas en Python.

En este caso obten el valor del elemento buscado de esta forma:

```
buscado[0]
```

ya que en realidad necesitas el valor del array `buscado` para realizar una correcta comparación. ( `if arreglo[i] == buscado` ) :

tu código sería:

```
from numpy import *
import random

def busquedaLineal(buscado, arreglo):
    encontrado = 0
    for i in range(len(arreglo)):
        if arreglo[i] == buscado:
            print "encontro:: ", buscado
            encontrado = 1
    return encontrado

arreglo = random.sample(range(25), 10)
buscado = random.sample(range(25), 1)

buscarElemento = busquedaLineal(buscado[0], arreglo)  # envia el valor de el elemento almacenado en el array buscado.

print "buscarElemento " , buscarElemento

if buscarElemento == 1:
   print 'Si se encontro en el arreglo'
else:
   print 'No se encontro en el arreglo'
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, Jorgesys!